# If enemy alive shoot if not then stop but it is not what it is doing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So what I'm doing is doing a pvz game but the objects is constantly firing so I implemented collision when the enemy is collided it will fire and stop when it is not so here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class attackRange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public towerAttacker towerAttacker;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "enemyCollider")
        {
            towerAttacker.shootStart();
            // It will detect once but once too many enemies are present it only counts as 1

        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
         if (collision.tag == "enemyCollider")
        {
            towerAttacker.shootStart();
        // It detects constantly but makes the object go into rapid fire mode
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "enemyCollider")
        {
            towerAttacker.StopAllCoroutines();
        // Stop when there is no collision detected
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on one object but screws on many objects

Comment: define screws..

Comment: for example it spawns 1 enemy then the object will fire 5x but when it spawns like x5 enemies the object will still fire 5x as it counts 5 enemy as 1 collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm think I know what's going on here. you might want to keep a list of existing enemies inside your range.

The issue I'm seeing is running "StopAllCoroutines()" when a collision ends  might be messing up your logic, because it stops listening for all the other collisions.

That OnTriggerExit2D should get executed when 1 collision ends, so you are stopping everything when the first enemy dissapears.

So what I believe you want to try is something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class attackRange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public towerAttacker towerAttacker;
    private List<string> activeEnemies = new List<string>();
    
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "enemyCollider")
        {
            // You might want to make sure there is no existing element with this name
            activeEnemies.Add(collision.gameObject.name);
            towerAttacker.shootStart();
            // It will detect once but once too many enemies are present it only counts as 1

        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
         if (collision.tag == "enemyCollider")
        {
            towerAttacker.shootStart();
        // It detects constantly but makes the object go into rapid fire mode
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "enemyCollider")
        {
            // Again, you might want to have some validation to make sure that string exists.
            activeEnemies.Remove(collision.gameObject.name);

            if(activeEnemies.Count() == 0) {
              // Stop when there is no collision detected
              towerAttacker.StopAllCoroutines();
              towerAttacker.shootStop();
            }
            // UPDATED to comment this line
            //towerAttacker.StopAllCoroutines();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

To make sure your attacker does not fire twice, you should update the towerAttacker class and the shootStart method.

And you'll need a new shootStop method, to reset that flag.

```
public class towerAttacker
{
    public bool isAttacking = false;
    
    void shootStart ()
    {
        if (!isAttacking)
        {
            // Do whatever your doing now
            ...
            this.isAtacking = true;
        }
    }

    void shootStop() {
      this.isAttacking = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem still happens where it counts all enemies in collider as 1 :((

Comment: I just realized, I left the "StopAllCoroutines" twice in the code. I just updated it to comment that line out. If you copied my code before, can you try again now? :D

Comment: it is working but when the colliders are near each other it double calls the function resulting into double shooting any fix?

Comment: You can add a boolean flag to the towerAttacker class called "isShooting", when you call "shootStart()" if that flag is false then shoot and set the flag to true, if it's true don't do anything.


Does that makes sense?

Comment: then how do I reset the value to false again?

Comment: public void shootStart()
    {
        if (isFiring == false)
        {
            // Start shooting animation courroutine IEnumerator
            StartCoroutine(shootingDelay());
        }

        else
        { 
            
        }
    }

Comment: I just updated the code in my answer, you just need a new method in there

Comment: it is not firing at all when inside the boolean